# Tokenize TEI-like text

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use spaCy to tokenize a text document, where named entities are wrapped in XML tags. E.g. [TEI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Encoding_Initiative)-like `<personName>Harry</personName> goes to <orgName>Hogwarts</orgName>`.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
txt = '<personName>Harry</personName> goes to <orgName>Hogwarts</orgName>. <personName>Sally</personName> lives in <locationName>London</locationName>.'
doc = nlp(txt)
sents = list(doc.sents)
for i, s in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print("{}: {}".format(i, s))
```

However, the XML tags cause a sentence split:

```
0: <personName>
1: Harry</personName> goes to <orgName>
2: Hogwarts</orgName>.
3: <personName>
4: Sally</personName> lives in <
5: locationName>
6: London</locationName>.
```

How can I get only 2 sentences?
I know that spaCy has a support for a [custom tokenizer](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#section-tokenization) but since the rest of the text is standard, I'd like to keep using the built-in one or perhaps build on top of it to recognize the XML annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do it by counting the tokens, and keeping track of which annotations each token has, a bit convoluted but does the job.

Preparation:

```
pattern = re.compile('</?[a-zA-Z_]+>')
pattern_start = re.compile('<[a-zA-Z_]+>')
pattern_end = re.compile('</[a-zA-Z_]+>')


# xml matches the pattern above
def annotate(xml):
    if xml[1] == '/':
        return (xml[2:-1] + '-end')
    else:
        return (xml[1:-1] + '-start')


nlp = spacy.load('en')
txt = '<personName>Harry Potter</personName> goes to \
    <orgName>Hogwarts</orgName>. <personName>Sally</personName> \
    lives in #<locationName>London</locationName>.'
words = txt.split()
stripped_words = []
# A mapping between token index and its annotations
annotations = {}
all_tokens = []
# A mapping between stripped_words index and whether it's preceded by a space
no_space = {}
```

Now let's traverse the words and check for annotations. We'll split each one to three parts: prefix, tag and suffix. E.g. for `<orgName>@Hogwarts.</orgName>` they'll be `@`, `Hogwarts`, and `.`, respectively.

```
for i, w in enumerate(words):
    matches = re.findall(pattern, w)
    w_annotations = []
    if len(matches) > 0:
        for m in matches:
            w_annotations.append(annotate(m))
        splitted_start = re.split(pattern_start, w)
        # TODO: we assume no word contains more than one annotation
        if len(splitted_start) > 1:
            prefix, rest = splitted_start
            if len(prefix) > 0:
                tokens = list(nlp(prefix))
                all_tokens.extend(tokens)
                # The prefix requires space before, but the tag itself not
                no_space[len(stripped_words) + 1] = True
                stripped_words.append(prefix)
        else:
            rest = splitted_start[0]
        splitted_end = re.split(pattern_end, rest)
        tag = splitted_end[0]
        stripped_words.append(tag)
        tokens = list(nlp(tag))
        n_tokens = len(all_tokens)
        for j, t in enumerate(tokens):
            annotations[n_tokens + j] = w_annotations
        all_tokens.extend(tokens)
        if len(splitted_end) > 1:
            suffix = splitted_end[1]
            if len(suffix) > 0:
                tokens = list(nlp(suffix))
                all_tokens.extend(tokens)
                no_space[len(stripped_words)] = True
                stripped_words.append(suffix)
    else:
        stripped_words.append(w)
        tokens = list(nlp(w))
        all_tokens.extend(tokens)
```

Finally, let's print the sentences with their annotations:

```
stripped_txt = stripped_words[0]
for i, w in enumerate(stripped_words[1:]):
    if (i + 1) in no_space:
        stripped_txt += w
    else:
        stripped_txt += ' ' + w

doc = nlp(stripped_txt)
n_tokens = 0
for i, s in enumerate(doc.sents):
    print("sentence{}: {}".format(i, s))
    for j, t in enumerate(list(s)):
        if n_tokens in annotations:
            anons = annotations[n_tokens]
        else:
            anons = []
        print("\t token{}: {}, annotations: {}".format(n_tokens, t, anons))
        n_tokens += 1
```

Result:

```
sentence0: Harry Potter goes to Hogwarts.
     token0: Harry, annotations: ['personName-start']
     token1: Potter, annotations: ['personName-end']
     token2: goes, annotations: []
     token3: to, annotations: []
     token4: Hogwarts, annotations: ['orgName-start', 'orgName-end']
     token5: ., annotations: []
sentence1: Sally lives in #London.
     token6: Sally, annotations: ['personName-start', 'personName-end']
     token7: lives, annotations: []
     token8: in, annotations: []
     token9: #, annotations: []
     token10: London, annotations: ['locationName-start', 'locationName-end']
     token11: ., annotations: []
```

Full Code:
https://gist.github.com/dimidd/1aba8b57643d5936f42670f0c5f344e4